# What is the monero stagenet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, monerod, stagenet

Realised there was no SE question for what the 'stagenet' is when setting up a monero wallet via the gui or CLI.

From my understanding the stagenet is a sandbox environment similar to testnet but is a copy of the 'current' mainnet whereas the testnet is a sandbox environment were you can test upcoming features on the monero network - is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stagenet mirrors mainnet's features. Stagenet was part of the Monero Lithium Luna release on March 29th 2018 https://getmonero.org/2018/03/29/monero-0.12.0.0-released.html

Stagenet does not use the same blockchain as mainnet, but it shares the same features and consensus algorithm. It is therefore perfect for testing transactions without having to spend real XMR. The mining difficulty for stagenet and testnet is very low, so it is easy to solo mine your own stagenet or testnet coins yourself using the Monero GUI.

To solo mine with monerod, enter the command: `start_mining <address> <number-of-threads>`

There is a block explorer for stagenet available here: http://162.210.173.150:8083/

Testnet is for testing new Monero features which are not yet available on stagenet or mainnet.

There is a block explorer for testnet available here: 
https://testnet.xmrchain.net/

Comment: Great, thought just as much but wanted to ask the question for others to see anyways.

Comment: update: see stagenet block explorer at https://stagenet.xmrchain.net/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quickly try sending moneroj, you can use my StageNet wallet. Please only send a few amount at a time (even better, send back after testing, or mine to it) so others could still have fun with it.

Currently 112.835 XMR available.

**Address**: *55LTR8KniP4LQGJSPtbYDacR7dz8RBFnsfAKMaMuwUNYX6aQbBcovzDPyrQF9KXF9tVU6Xk3K8no1BywnJX6GvZX8yJsXvt*

**Seeds**: *vocal either anvil films dolphin zeal bacon cuisine quote syndrome rejoices envy okay pancakes tulips lair greater petals organs enmity dedicated oust thwart tomorrow tomorrow*

**Secret view key**: *0a1a38f6d246e894600a3e27238a064bf5e8d91801df47a17107596b1378e501*

**Public view key**: *eedc5c8d9e3b0a8963c04fa980e4cbaa31ac5c427e21f841a7e93f279aa2fa46*

**Secret spend key**: *722bbfcf99a9b2c9e700ce857850dd8c4c94c73dca8d914c603f5fee0e365803*

**Public spend key**: *5c8044a93a0d4b73fdd9698b1c8935d3bcae206e26590ce425c2085e2fb81db3*

May the privacy be with you!

Comment: For anyone who will use it, please take small amounts only, or better, return it after testing. On the 15th of January, someone just draw out 136.000 in 39 transactions, leaving the wallet almost empty. I will mine again for a while on it, but please, be responsible.